# Scroll the list of infinite dots in circular manner(Circular Infinite Recycler View)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

As shown in the image there are multiple dots, I want to scroll them in the directions of the arrow and should be clickable. I thought about making a listView and then somehow bending it in the shape of a ring but I had no idea how to do it. Please suggest me some idea how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) for this module and create custom viewPager transaction for rotating in both direction clock vice or anti clock vice.

[ViewPager Transaction](https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419)